# R ggline changing x axis labels on chart without changing the actual data

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I have a chart[image: with 4 different groups along x axis]

I which to change the names of the values along the axis from 1 2 3 4 to Chrome, Internet Explorer, Firefox, Netscape. However I do not know how to do this

I have found [a similar thread, but cant seem to get the changes I need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45759295/ggplot-change-x-axis-labels-without-changing-underlying-data)

Any ideas please?

```
ggline(DF8, x = "web_browser_as_numeric", y = "ages", 
   add = c("mean_se", "jitter"), 
   order = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
   ylab = "Age", xlab = "Browser")



 dput(DF8)
structure(list(ages = c(49, 47, 53, 45, 49, 51, 45, 45, 51, 43, 
49, 51, 45, 49, 37, 45, 47, 59, 55, 39, 53, 51, 43, 51, 49, 47, 
41, 53, 49, 39, 47, 51, 55, 43, 59, 49, 53, 57, 47, 41, 55, 47, 
53, 41, 57, 43, 49, 57, 55, 61), web_browser_as_numeric = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = c("ordered", "factor"
))), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Add `scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Chrome", "Internet Explorer", "Firefox", "Netscape"))`

Comment: Thanks @stefan in which line of the code? `ggline(DF8, x = "web_browser_as_numeric", y = "ages", 
       add = c("mean_se", "jitter"), 
       order = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
       ylab = "Age", xlab = "Browser")' as I am getting errors when I am trying to add it.  'Error: Element 6 of .I must be a vector, not a `ScaleDiscretePosition/ScaleDiscrete/Scale/ggproto/gg` object'

Comment: Add it to gggline like so `ggline(...) + scale_x_discrete(..)`.